# Jekyll page.next.url not working while page.next.title is ok

Tags: jekyll

I am using jekyll to build a image gallery, http://comics.daozhang.info, but when I try to implement the next page and previous page, It cannot access `page.next.url` or `page.previous.url`. However, `page.next.title` is available. Isn't the `page.next` or `page.previous` a template argument?

I am not sure why this happens. Can you guys give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

source code:

```
<div class="pin-view-arrows">
{% if page.previous %}
  <a style="visibility: visible; position: fixed; right: 0px;" class="next x layer-view" href="{{ page.next.url }}">{{page.previous.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
{% if page.next %}
  <a style="visibility: visible; position: fixed; left: 0px;" class="prev x layer-view" href="{{ page.previous.url }}">{{page.next.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
```

after generated:

```
<a style="visibility: visible; position: fixed; left: 0px;" class="prev x layer-view" href="">Bone antennas</a>
```

Comment: I think it is due to that there is only 2 post in my site, so they work abnormally. After I posted some more images, they work normally now. so I think this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [paginator](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#paginator), in the *_config.yml* define the post per page:

*paginate: 1 # Posts per page*

and can easily manage pages. It must be defined to use the paginator variable.

Comment: That seems a very good solution for my site, i will try and see if it can works. Thanks a lot for your advice.